# Can I use alternatives to MPNS?

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, cloud

I can't setup an Azure account, because I have a prepaid credit card.
So my question is straight: Are there alternatives I could use for a Windows (Phone) 8 app?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Azure != MPNS**.

You can send Push notifications to a Windows Phone device without being registered to Azure.

While Azure's Notification Hub eases the process of sending notifications to different platforms, it is not mandatory. You can send notifications by communicating directly with each platform's notification service without going through Azure. In case of Windows Phone, you will need to communicate directly with MPNS.

You don't need any registration to use this service.

Following link shows how to create and send a push notification. You basically need to create a POST request:

[Sending push notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202945%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)